# Zabbix-add script parameter to trigger

Tags: linux, monitoring, zabbix

i created a script which monitor rundeck Jobs status, added rundeck to Zabbix,i want to run this script from rundeck server and to show status in Zabbix dashboard,
here is script:

```
#!/bin/bash

 curl -s -H "Accept: application/json" -X GET "http://172.30.61.88:4440/api/20/project/demo/executions?authtoken=ZP9znayUp3Ktp26uQjSQGnEfTzDvqPDA"  | python -m json.tool > 1.json

jq -r '.|[.executions[] | select(.job.name != null)]  | sort_by(.id)  | reverse  | .[0]  | [.status, .job.name, ."date-ended".date] | @csv' 1.json > 1.csv

sed 's/,/ /g' 1.csv>st.txt
while read status name date; do
case "$status" in
"\"aborted\"")
echo -1
;;
 "\"failed\"")
echo -1 +  $name
;;
 "\"succeeded\"")
echo 0
;;
*) echo 0 + $name
esac
exit 0
done<st.txt
```

How to add script output parameter $name (job name) to trigger

[image]

Comment: My guess: UserParameter=rundeck,cd /home/ && a.sh

Comment: in fact UserParameter=rundeck,/home/a.sh did the trick

Comment: i solved it by running :

    systemctl stop zabbix-agent.service
    
    chown -R zabbix:zabbix /var/log/zabbix
    chown -R zabbix:zabbix /var/run/zabbix
    chmod -R 775 /var/log/zabbix/
    chmod -R 775 /var/run/zabbix/
    /usr/sbin/zabbix_agentd -c /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it by adding {ITEM.VALUE} in trigger name field